# Una parola per 'frasi fatte'

Tags: word-choice

C'è qualcuno che mi aiuta a trovare una parola che possa sostituire 'frasi fatte', quelle che si ripetono per significare qualcosa, ma che in realtà sono vuote, cioè dette come fosse un rito ripeterle -- tanto che alla fine appaiono vere e proprie banalià, come:

- "Pieno impegno dell'Italia nella lotta al terrorismo";
- "Un pensiero particolare alle persone con disabilità, agli anziani che sono o si sentono soli, ai malati";
- ...
- ...

Comment: Potresti fare un esempio?

Comment: Una parola singola? Altrimenti "Frasi di convenienza" calzerebbe abbastanza.

Comment: Entrambi gli esempi sono tratti da parole di Mattarella: è voluto?

Comment: No, è un caso, @dag. Tuttavia è ben noto che in Italia il ruolo del Presidente della Repubbliva è quello di dire frasi di rito, non a caso, per condensarle tutte, è previsto l'apposito discorso di fine anno.

Comment: Rileggi la costituzione, Elberich. Il “ruolo” del Presidente è tutt'altro. Poi pronuncia anche il discorso di fine anno, ma è il meno.

Answer (score 8):

Che ne dici di *stereotipo*, *luogo comune* o *cliché*?

Un'espressione che mi ha sempre colpito è anche quella di "frase precofenzionata", che trasmette proprio l'idea di qualcosa detta senza la minima partecipazione o il minimo sforzo da parte del parlante, ma partorita in maniera assolutamente asettica e propinata all'interlocutore.

Comment: Attenzione, le tre parole che menzioni sono riferite ad un "concetto" stilizzato ("stereotype" in inglese e "cliché" in francese), non ad un "modo di dire" comune ("slang" o "set phrase"). Difficile tradurre il concetto in italiano usando una parola sola.

Comment: Vero. Non so però se @Elberich Schneider volesse *una* parola (Ǝ) o *una sola* (Ǝ!).